# Timespan of groups in Pandas timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

Can I receive the covered timespans of groups resulting from groupby operations without using my own lambda function?

Currently I have the below solution but I am wondering if the pandas API not already has this built-in somehow?
To describe what I'm doing in the data prep part: My task is to find out when and especially for how long the boolean flag is True. I found that ndimage.label-ing is an efficient way to deal with non-contiguous data blocks. But I am open to any other cool suggestions!

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.ndimage import label
# data preparation
idx = pd.date_range(start='now', periods = 100, freq='min')
df= pd.DataFrame(randn(100), index=idx, columns=['data'])
df['mybool'] = df.data > 0
df['label'] = label(df.mybool)[0]
# my actual question:
df.groupby('label').apply(lambda x:x.index[-1] - x.index[0])
```

Basically, I subtract the last timestamp from the first for each group.
This results in:

```
label
0       01:37:00
1       00:00:00
2       00:01:00
3       00:01:00
4       00:01:00
5       00:02:00
6       00:00:00
7       00:10:00
8       00:00:00
9       00:01:00
10      00:02:00
11      00:00:00
12      00:01:00
13      00:04:00
14      00:02:00
15      00:01:00
16      00:00:00
17      00:00:00
18      00:00:00
19      00:01:00
20      00:00:00
21      00:01:00
22      00:02:00
23      00:00:00
24      00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

To reiterate my question: Does the pandas API offer a trick that does the same without using applying a lambda function or maybe even without grouping first?

Comment: try df.groupby(..).last() - df.groupby(..).first()

Comment: but last() and first() don't access the index? They provide the value of the boolean, not the value of the timestamp for it.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 100 entries, 2013-10-25 00:45:49 to 2013-10-25 02:24:49
Freq: T
Data columns (total 3 columns):
data      100  non-null values
mybool    100  non-null values
label     100  non-null values
dtypes: bool(1), float64(1), int32(1)

In [12]: df['date'] = df.index

In [14]: g = df.groupby('label')['date']

In [15]: g.last()-g.first()
Out[15]: 

label
0       01:39:00
1       00:03:00
2       00:00:00
3       00:04:00
4       00:02:00
5       00:00:00
6       00:01:00
7       00:02:00
8       00:08:00
9       00:00:00
10      00:00:00
11      00:06:00
12      00:07:00
13      00:00:00
14      00:00:00
15      00:04:00
16      00:00:00
17      00:01:00
18      00:00:00
19      00:01:00
20      00:00:00
21      00:00:00
22      00:00:00
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This also have the benefit of being transparent/obvious what's going on.

Comment: Interestingly, df['date'] = df.index takes more than 100 seconds with an index of > 17 million timestamps. But `df.index.name='date';g=df.reset_index().groupby('label')['date']` takes only 90 ms !